# How to migrate DB2 z/OS data to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql, data-migration, db2-zos

As part of the data migration from DB2 z/OS (Mainframe) to Google cloud SQL, I don't see the direct service/connector provided by google or IBM. So, I am exploring the option to move the data to MySQL first and then to Cloud SQL.

I could see the solution to migrate from Mysql to cloud SQL but not DB2 to MYSQL.

I searched in google for this need but I could not find the resolution.

Will it be connected based on JDBC connection or something else?

Comment: What options have you tried ? There are some results when you look for moving data from DB2 to MySQL.

Comment: Hi, I prefer to migrate db2 z/os data to mysql on-prim and then move to cloud SQL using database migration service(mysql to cloud sql). this approach works with some limited data like 16 TB per table. If it contains more data cloud spanner is the option but not sure how to migrate the data from mysql to cloud spanner. if you have any idea please let me know.

Comment: Regarding migrating MySQL to Spanner, I suggest the following docs https://cloud.google.com/architecture/migrating-mysql-to-spanner. Did you manage to migrate from from Db2 for z/OS to MySQL already?

Comment: My approach is changed now. There are many complexities in having the storage layer mySQL just for data movement alone. I am trying to explore options like - unload DB2 into CSV file => move to cloud storage => load into Cloud SQL. I am still searching how to do it in this way. Please let me know if you have any idea how to load CSV file corresponding to MySQL data tyes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach of migrating first to CSV and then to Cloud SQL for MySQL sounds good. As you said, you will need to create a Cloud Storage Bucket [1], upload your CSV file to the bucket, and follow the steps here [2] corresponding to MySQL.

[1] - https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/creating-buckets

[2] - https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/import-export-csv#import

Comment: Yah I have gone thru the document. thanks

Comment: Just consider, if I am planning to migrate OLTP Db2 data to GCP. how to manage the data ingestion to cloud storage and then to Cloud SQL? Because DB2 unload file will be extracted based on Unload JCL and then need to load into CLoud SQL. As it is a OLTP, do I need to extract frequently (say some 10 minutes for example) ? Because in OLTP purpose cloud sql is recommended than BigQuery.